# Finding frequency of characters both upper case and lower case in a file c program

Tags: c, algorithm, uppercase, lowercase

I tried a lot of thing but when I chose 2 to count upper case and lower case separately the result was garbage, I don't know what is wrong with this, while doesn't care if lower case or upper case it still works correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int i,h,k ,count[26] = {0}, nam[26] = {0};
  char c[1000];
  FILE *fptr;
  fptr=fopen("tep1.txt","w");
  if(fptr==NULL){
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("a String please:\n");
  gets(c);
  fprintf(fptr,"%s",c);
  fclose(fptr);
  printf("discern between upper case and lower case? 0=no, 1=yes");
  scanf("%d",&h);

  if(h==0){    
    while (c[i] != '\0'){     
      if (c[i] >= 'a' && c[i] <= 'z') 
        count[c[i]-'a']++;

      if (c[i]>='A' &&c[i]<='Z')
        count[c[i]-'A']++;
      i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){
      if (count[i] != 0)
        printf("%c %c appears %d times on file.\n",i+'a',i+'A',count[i]);
    }
    return 0;
  }
  if(h==1){    
    while (c[i]|c[k] != '\0') {      
      if (c[i] >= 'a' && c[i] <= 'z') 
        count[c[i]-'a']++;
      i++;
      if (c[k]>='A' &&c[k]<='Z')
        nam[c[k]-'A']++;
      k++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){
      if (count[i] != 0)
        printf("%c %c appears %d times on file.\n",i+'a',count[i]);      
    }

    for (k = 0; k < 26; k++){
      if (nam[k] != 0)
        printf("%c %c appears %d times on file.\n",k+'A',nam[k]);      
    }

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Add output also, so that we can get clarification of your problem.

Comment: w  and (some unknown character) appears 26856400 times on file

Comment: I didn't get any problem with your code. http://ideone.com/dOfdEh

Comment: `int i,h,k` : `i` and `k` need initialize. `printf("%c %c appears %d times on file.\n",i+'a',count[i]);` and `printf("%c %c appears %d times on file.\n",k+'A',nam[k]);` arguments mismatch.

Comment: thanks for your help Avinash, try option 1, option 0 has no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First, you have to initialize your integers like `i = 0`.
- Second thing is for count upper and lower case, problem is in printing.In print function you have written %c two times and one %d, but gives only two arguments.
- Just replace your printf function from,

  `printf("%c %c appears %d times on file.\n",i+'a',count[i]);`

  to

  `printf("%c appears %d times on file.\n",i+'a',count[i]);` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Wow Thank you, I didn't know it was that easy, have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems in this part of the code:

```
while (c[i]|c[k] != '\0') 
{
  if (c[i] >= 'a' && c[i] <= 'z') 
     count[c[i]-'a']++;
  i++;
  if (c[k]>='A' &&c[k]<='Z')
     nam[c[k]-'A']++;
  k++;
}
```

You don't need two counters; you simply need the two arrays `count` and `nam`.  Your loop structure for parsing each letter should be the same.

Take a step back from the code, and think of what your loop structure should do.  *Regardless* of whether you pay attention to case, you should iterate through the characters of the line in the same way.

Incidentally, the logic in the `while` statement is wrong.  If you wanted anything at all with c[i] and c[k], you would have wanted

```
while (c[i] != '\0' && c[k] != '\0')
```

What the code you have does is bitwise-OR the values of `c[i]` and `c[k]`, and see if they're equal to `'\0'`, i.e. equal to 0.  Until `i` and `k` are both pointing to a null character, this won't happen for a long time.  But again, your while loop to iterate through the line should be the same as in the `h == 0` case.

As far as I can tell, you don't need your `k` counter anywhere.

Comment: I removed k and did && but the output still garbage. Thanks for pointing that out.